# Rigid object getting stuck on container bounding box before falling in

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to have a little pill shaped object fall into a bag. When the pill falls, from frame 35 to 80 it seems to halt on the top edge of the bounding box of the container. After that 50 frames, it falls into the container. I can't figure out why it's stalling there at the bag opening. Here are images of the settings for the pill and bag. Also, you can see the location the pill is stuck at.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. The pill was reacting to an object that I had shut off. "Bag 1".